# Ajax refresh of div not pulling in new forum posts

Tags: ajax, wordpress, refresh

I'm using Simple:Press in Wordpress, and I have an Ajax auto-refresh code in the header, which refreshes ONLY the div that has the newest thread posts.
The page refreshes just fine, but won't load in any new posts in that thread.

Here's the code in my header:

```
    <script>
    var refreshId = setInterval(function()
    {
        $('.sfposttable').fadeOut("fast").load('response.php').fadeIn("fast");
    }, 60000);
    </script>
```

Any ideas why the div refreshes, but doesn't pull in any new posts?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use first

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var refreshId = setInterval(function()
    {
        $('.sfposttable').fadeOut("fast").load('response.php').fadeIn("fast");
    }, 60000);

});
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/943UA/

Also you may want to change the refresh time: 60000 -> 1 minute make it 2000 -> 2 sec for test purpose.

Comment: Thanks, that works great on refreshing. I believe my problem is in my 'response.php' which doesn't seem to pull in any new posts.